# viewbadger show and hide

Tags: java, android

I'm using this link [`this`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) to show number of notification in my apps. I can show it with using:

```
ImageView target = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(getActivity(), target);
badge.setText("99+");
badge.setText(notifyCount);
badge.setTextSize(7);

badge.show();
```

But when i try to hide it using `badge.hide();` it fails.  Is there another way to hide the `ImageView`?

Comment: Feel free to explain what "it fails" means.

Comment: so that is a view.. try using `badge.setVisibilty(View.GONE);` or `badge.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);` according to your condition

Comment: @laalto it fails mean the badge still showing even i used the hide method

Comment: @e_sha tried but still cant